# GTK2: Expose Event, blit part of a PNG file

Tags: c, cairo, gtk2

Can I somehow blit a part of a PNG file in the expose event in GTK2? I can load the PNG in a Pixbuf and use Cairo to use the Pixbuf as a brush, but I dont know how I can only use, lets say, the rectangle `(1,1,10,10)` of the PNG as a brush. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cairo_image_surface_create_from_png`](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-PNG-Support.html#cairo-image-surface-create-from-png) is a good way to create a Cairo-centric PNG surface. You could then use [`cairo_surface_create_for_rectangle`](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-cairo-surface-t.html#cairo-surface-create-for-rectangle) to restrict the size of the `cairo_surface_t`. Then you use [`cairo_set_source_surface`](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-set-source-surface) to use your surface returned from `create_for_rectangle` as a source or brush.